Cannot access git in Jenkins
I want to set up a jenkins server for my maven projects. I have managed to run Jenkins in a docker container on my NAS, so far so good.
I have also been able to access a demo github project and build it with a maven job in Jenkins.
However, I want to access my repositories on my own git server. I have changed the maven project in Jenkings accordingly and entered the credentials in Jenkins Credential Manager where they are stored (Manage Jenkings - Credentials).
Unfortunately Jenkins can't check out my sources from the git repository. I get the following error message:
Started by user Rudolf Ziegaus
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/HolidaysAPI
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 7d1a3e04-f2e7-44f5-bd3e-fcef32bada51
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/HolidaysAPI/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url root@nas2:/opt/git/HolidaysAPI # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from root@nas2:/opt/git/HolidaysAPI
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.39.2'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- root@nas2:/opt/git/HolidaysAPI +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from root@nas2:/opt/git/HolidaysAPI
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:999)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1241)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1248)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:649)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:521)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- root@nas2:/opt/git/HolidaysAPI +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
root@nas2: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2846)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:635)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:997)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE

I have tried to access the repository "manually" in Jenkins, meaning I have attached to the container as user jenkins and created the necessary directoires manually and was able to clone the repository without problems. I entered my password manually when git asked for it. Everything worked without problems, so I think there's no problem with the privileges. I assume that git cannot access the credentials although I entered them in the credential manager.
How can I get this to work? Where do I have to put my credentials that everything works?
